# Flutter CupertinoPicker not rendering

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Trying to make a Flutter CupertinoPicker work on Flutter 1.7. No fancy stuff, just the basic code inside a Scaffold body...

Only using the mandatory elements...tried even sample code of other people, nothing works.

```
CupertinoPicker(
     itemExtent: 30.0,
     onSelectedItemChanged: (int idx) {
       setState(() {
          _prayer.rebuild((b) =>
             b..category = listOfStrings[idx]);
          });
       },
     children: List<Widget>.generate(
     listOfStrings.length,
     (int i) {
        return Text('Dummy Text');
     },
   ),
 )
```

```
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#fdf27 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#052f5 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#0d6c9 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#fdf27 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#052f5 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#0d6c9 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '>' was called on null.
```

Android Picker works...
Is there a need that the parent Widget should be Cupertino based or something ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Expanded(      
    child:  
      
      CupertinoPicker(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {
        },
        itemExtent: 50.0,
        children:new List<Widget>.generate(
                        companyList.length, (int index) {
                      return new Center(
                        child: new Text(
                          "${companyList[index]}",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,fontFamily: 
                           'HelveticaRegular'),),
                      );})
     ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it in two ways. As the answer is in the logcat **RenderFlex**.

We need to provide the height either using **Container**

```
Container(
            height: 200.0,
            child: CupertinoPicker(
     itemExtent: 30.0,
     onSelectedItemChanged: (int idx) {
       setState(() {
          _prayer.rebuild((b) =>
             b..category = listOfStrings[idx]);
          });
       },
     children: List<Widget>.generate(
     listOfStrings.length,
     (int i) {
        return Text('Dummy Text');
     },
   ),
 )
)
```

**Or**

Using the **Expanded** in case of Row and Column

```
Expanded(
      child: CupertinoPicker(
     itemExtent: 30.0,
     onSelectedItemChanged: (int idx) {
       setState(() {
          _prayer.rebuild((b) =>
             b..category = listOfStrings[idx]);
          });
       },
     children: List<Widget>.generate(
     listOfStrings.length,
     (int i) {
        return Text('Dummy Text');
     },
   ),
 )
)
```